# Query a second dataframe based on the values of first dataframe. [spark] [pyspark]

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a specific requirement where I need to query a dataframe based on a range condition.

The values of the range come from the rows of another dataframe and so I will have as many queries as the rows in this different dataframe.

Using collect() in my scenario seems to be the bottleneck because it brings every row to the driver.

**Sample example:**

I need to execute a query on table 2 for every row in table 1

Table 1:

| ID1 | Num1 | Num2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 3 |
| 2 | 40 | 4 |

---

Table 2

| ID2 | Num3 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 |
| 2 | 39 |
| 3 | 22 |
| 4 | 12 |

For the first row in table 1, I create a range [10-3,10+3] =[7,13] => this becomes the range for the first query.

For the second row in table 2, I create a range [40-4,40+4] =[36,44] => this becomes the range for the second query.

I am currently doing collect() and iterating over the rows to get the values. I use these values as ranges in my queries for Table 2.

Output of Query 1:

| ID2 | Num3 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 |
| 4 | 12 |

Output of Query 2:

| ID2 | Num3 |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 39 |

Since the number of rows in table 1 is very large, doing a collect() operation is costly.

And since the values are numeric, I assume a join won't work.

Any help in optimizing this task is appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide a minimal reproducible example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example , provide your input & expected samples of your dataset

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the question with additional details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you want your output to look like, you could solve this with a join. Consider the following code:

```
case class FirstType(id1: Int, num1: Int, num2: Int)
case class Bounds(id1: Int, lowerBound: Int, upperBound: Int)
case class SecondType(id2: Int, num3: Int)

val df = Seq((1, 10, 3), (2, 40, 4)).toDF("id1", "num1", "num2").as[FirstType]
df.show
+---+----+----+
|id1|num1|num2|
+---+----+----+
|  1|  10|   3|
|  2|  40|   4|
+---+----+----+

val df2 = Seq((1, 9), (2, 39), (3, 22), (4, 12)).toDF("id2", "num3").as[SecondType]
df2.show
+---+----+
|id2|num3|
+---+----+
|  1|   9|
|  2|  39|
|  3|  22|
|  4|  12|
+---+----+

val bounds = df.map(x => Bounds(x.id1, x.num1 - x.num2, x.num1 + x.num2))
bounds.show
+---+----------+----------+
|id1|lowerBound|upperBound|
+---+----------+----------+
|  1|         7|        13|
|  2|        36|        44|
+---+----------+----------+

val test = bounds.join(df2, df2("num3") >= bounds("lowerBound") && df2("num3") <= bounds("upperBound"))
test.show
+---+----------+----------+---+----+
|id1|lowerBound|upperBound|id2|num3|
+---+----------+----------+---+----+
|  1|         7|        13|  1|   9|
|  2|        36|        44|  2|  39|
|  1|         7|        13|  4|  12|
+---+----------+----------+---+----+
```

In here, I do the following:

- Create 3 case classes to be able to use typed datasets later on
- Create the 2 dataframes
- Create an auxilliary dataframe called `bounds`, which contains the lower/upper bounds
- Join the second dataframe onto that auxilliary one

As you can see, the `test` dataframe contains the result. For each unique combination of the `id1`, `lowerBound` and `upperBound` columns you'll get the different dataframes that you wanted if you look at the `id2` and `num3` columns only.

You could, for example use a `groupBy` operation to group by these 3 columns and then do whatever you wanted with the output `KeyValueGroupedDataset` (something like `test.groupBy("id1", "lowerBound", "upperBound")`). From there on it depends on what you want: if you want to apply an operation to each dataset for each of the bounds you could use the `mapValues` method of `KeyValueGroupedDataset`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was able to understand your approach. I will try to implement this for my use case and get back. Thanks a lot for taking the time.

Comment: This worked. I am accepting this as an answer. Thanks a lot.